# troubles on wamp localhost port 8080

Tags: magento-1.9, localhost, wamp

Im getting this error on http://localhost:8080/
Magento ver. 1.9.3.10
Any help is appreciated.

Notice: Undefined variable: cart  in C:\wamp64\www\app\design\frontend\default\hardwood\template\callouts\left_col.phtml on line 60

Answer (score 0):

It seems that on line 60 of `C:\wamp64\www\app\design\frontend\default\hardwood\template\callouts\left_col.phtml`, you have a call to a variable called `$cart` that has not been defined.

You will have to define it or to remove any call of this variable if this is an useless variable.